# Baruch's proof of Kirillov's conjecture

Tags: rt.representation-theory

Baruch's paper (Annals of Math. 158 (2003), 207-252) proves the following statement, originally claimed by Kirillov.

**Theorem.** Let $G=\mathrm{GL}_n(K)$ where $K$ is either $\mathbb{R}$ or $\mathbb{C}$, and let $P=P_n(K)$ be the subgroup of matrices in $\mathrm{GL}_n(K)$ consisting of matrices whose last row is $(0,0,\dots,0,1)$. If $\pi$ is an irreducible unitary representation of $G$ on a Hilbert space $H$ then $\pi|P$ is irreducible.

Representation theory is not my expertise, so the following question might be very basic.

**Question.** On page 208 the author considers an arbitrary bounded linear operator $R:H\to H$ which commutes with $\pi(p)$ for all $p\in P$. He also considers, for any $f\in C_c^\infty(G)$, the distribution $\Lambda_R(f)=\mathrm{trace}(R\pi(f))$. Then he says: "It is easy to see that $\Lambda_R$ is an eigendistribution with respect to the center of the universal enveloping algebra associated to $G$." What is the meaning of "eigendistribution" here, and why is the statement true?

Comment: I have not looked at the paper, but I guess an eigendistribution is justa distribution which is an eigenvalue. That is, when you act on it by a central element in the enveloping algebra, it gets multiplied by a scalar.

Comment: Thanks, Mariano, that would make sense. I hope someone can clarify this with proof.

Comment: Let us take R=Identity. Do we agree that trace( pi(f)) is eigendistribution ? It seems it is character. Center of U(g) should act on it by scalars.

Comment: And welcome to the 10k club, GH!

Comment: Dear David Roberts: Thank you, that was very kind of you!

Answer (score 3):

Since $\pi$ is irreducible, the center of the enveloping algebra acts by scalars (by Schur's lemma). Hence, for $X\in Z(\mathcal{U}G)$ we have $$\Lambda_R(Xf)=Tr(R\pi(Xf))=Tr(Rd\pi(X)\pi(f))=d\pi(X)Tr(R\pi(f))=d\pi(X)\Lambda_R(f)$$
where $d\pi$ is the derived representation extended to the enveloping algebra.

Comment: And for this to make sense, $\pi(f)$ is trace-class, which is not obvious.

Comment: @Paul: Right, this is really not trivial. On the other hand, the OP took it for granted.

Comment: I don't think "Schur's lemma" is completely obvious in this setting either, especially when $G = GL_n \mathbb R$ is disconnected.

Comment: @Alain: Thank you. At the moment I only see that $X$ commutes with $\pi(g)$ for $g\in\exp(G)$. Also, I think $\Lambda_R(Xf)=d\pi(-X)\Lambda_R(f)$. Indeed, the left hand side is the $t$-derivative at $t=0$ of the operator $\int_G f(e^{tX}g)\pi(g)\ dg$, using that $X$ commutes with $\pi(g)$, and the last integral equals $\int_G f(g)\pi(e^{-tX}g)\ dg$. Am I missing something?

Comment: I completed the argument, please check. Assume that $f$ is supported on the coset $h\exp(G)$, so that the left translate $L(h^{-1})f$ has support in $\exp(G)$. By Schur's lemma we have
$$ \pi(h)\pi(Xf) = \pi(L(h^{-1}) Xf) = \pi(X L(h^{-1}) f) = d\pi(-X) \pi(L(h^{-1}) f)=d\pi(-X) \pi(h)\pi(f). $$ It follows that $\pi(Xf)=d\pi(-X) \pi(f)$ for any $h$, whence for any $f\in C_c^\infty(G)$. Now the argument can be finished as before.

Comment: @Faisal: You made a very good point: I overlooked the fact that $GL_n(\mathbb{R})$ is not connected (and connectedness is important, as GH's computation shows). If the restriction of $\pi$ to $GL_n^+(\mathbb{R})$ (=matrices with positive determinant) is still irreducible, then my argument goes through. If $n$ is odd, this will be the case (since $GL_n(\mathbb{R})$ is then a direct product). The case of even $n$ remains unclear to me.

Comment: @Alain: In my last comment I attempted to complete your argument. Please tell me if it is OK. I am implicitly using that $\exp(G)$ contains the component of the identity.

Comment: @GH: $\exp(G)$ is contained in the connected component of identity, and contains a neighborhood of identity, hence generates the connected component of identity. So if the group is connected (e.g. $GL_n(\mathbb{C})$, as mentioned in the OP), your argument + Schur's lemma do the job. Be aware that you take $X$ in the Lie algebra $\mathfrak{g}$, not in the universal enveloping algebra $\mathcal{U}(\mathfrak{g})$. Let me also correct a sign: to be coherent with the left regular representation, you should define $(Xf)(g)$ as the derivative at $t=0$ of $f(e^{-tX}g)$.

Comment: @Alain, I tried again to complete your argument. Please read and check my response below. Thank you.

Comment: @Alain: In the spirit of your second response, one can see that $d\pi(X)$ acts by scalars whenever $X$ lies in the center of $\mathcal{U}(\mathfrak{gl}(n,\mathbb{C}))$. This is because this (smaller) center is generated by $n$ symmetric Casimir-like operators, see Prop.12.3.15 in Goldfeld-Hundley: Automorphic representations and L-functions for the general linear group, Volume 2. I read somewhere that the same feature holds for any real reductive group (in which case $\mathfrak{gl}(n,\mathbb{C})$ is replaced by the complexified Lie-algebra), but I could not find a reference so far.

Comment: @GH And you claim that representation theory is not your expertise! (:-)

Comment: @Alain: It really isn't :-( I come from classical analytic number theory, and try to catch up with representation theory.

Comment: Actually, the center of $\mathcal{U}(\mathfrak{gl}(n,\mathbb{R}))$ lies in the center of $\mathcal{U}(\mathfrak{gl}(n,\mathbb{C}))$, because if an element of $\mathcal{U}(\mathfrak{gl}(n,\mathbb{C}))$ commutes with $\mathfrak{gl}(n,\mathbb{R})$, then it also commutes with $\mathfrak{gl}(n,\mathbb{C})$. So the argument in Goldfeld-Hundley, which is an elaboration of Alain's idea, justifies the original response above and takes care of Faisal's concerns as well.

Comment: @Alain: I learned more about $Z(\mathcal{U}\mathfrak{g})$, where $\mathfrak{g}$ is the Lie algebra of $G$. It turns out that $Z(\mathcal{U}\mathfrak{g})$ equals the set of $G'$-invariants of $\mathcal{U}\mathfrak{g}$, where $G'$ denotes the subgroup of $\mathrm{Aut}(\mathfrak{g})$ generated by $\exp(\mathrm{ad}(x))$, $(\mathrm{ad}(x)$ nilpotent, $x\in\mathfrak{g}$. In particular, when the image of $\mathrm{Ad}:G\to\mathrm{Aut}(\mathfrak{g})$ lies in $G'$, we have that $Z(\mathcal{U}\mathfrak{g})$ is fixed by $\mathrm{Ad}(G)$. I continue in next comment.

Comment: This condition is included in the Harish-Chandra class of which $\mathrm{GL}_n(\mathbb{R})$ is a member.

Answer (score 3):

The following answer to my question is based on Alain Valette's response, it is too long for a comment.

For $X\in Z(\mathcal{U}\mathfrak{g})$ the actions of $X$ and $G^0=\mathrm{GL}^+_n(\mathbb{R})$ commute, hence we are done by Schur's lemma when $\pi|G^0$ is irreducible. Otherwise $\pi|G^0$ is the sum of two irreducible representations $(\rho^\pm,H^\pm)$ which are conjugates of each other by the matrix $i:=\mathrm{diag}(-1,1,\dots,1)\in P$. In particular, $\pi(i)$ interchanges $H^\pm$. By Schur's lemma, $X$ acts on $H^{\pm}$ by some scalars $c^\pm(X)\in\mathbb{C}$. We are done if $c^+(X)=c^-(X)$.

Assume that $c^+(X)\neq c^-(X)$, and let $f\in C_0^\infty(G)$ be supported in a connected component of $G$. As $R$ commutes with $\pi(i)$, we have
$$\mathrm{trace}(R\pi(Xf))=\mathrm{trace}(R\pi(i)\pi(Xf)\pi(i)).$$
Note that $\pi(f)$ either leaves the spaces $H^\pm$ invariant or it maps one into the other, depending on whether $f$ is supported in $G^0$ or in $G^0i$. In either case the previous equation
together with
$$\Lambda_R(f)=\mathrm{trace}(R\pi(f))=\mathrm{trace}(R\pi(i)\pi(f)\pi(i))$$
yields
$$c^+(X)\Lambda_R(f)=c^-(X)\Lambda_R(f).$$
This shows that $\Lambda_R(f)=0$, hence $\Lambda_R=0$ as a whole.

Comment: Nice use of the extra assumption that $\pi|_P$ commutes with $R$.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a complement on GH's answer, too long for a comment. Assume $n=2$, and write $GL_2^+(\mathbb{R})$ as $SL_2(\mathbb{R})\times\mathbb{R}$, so that $\mathcal{U}(G)\simeq\mathcal{U}(SL_2(\mathbb{R})\otimes\mathcal{U}(\mathbb{R})$ and $Z(\mathcal{U}(G))\simeq Z(\mathcal{U}(SL_2(\mathbb{R}))\otimes\mathcal{U}(\mathbb{R})$. Now $\mathcal{U}(\mathbb{R})=\mathbb{C}[X]$ and, as is well-known, $Z(\mathcal{U}(SL_2(\mathbb{R}))=\mathbb{C}[\Omega]$, where $\Omega$ is the Casimir operator. Now the adjoint action by the diagonal matrix $i=diag(-1,1)$ fixes $\Omega$, so that (using GH's notations) $c^+=c^-$, without appealing to the extra assumption on $\pi$. I'm not sure that this generalizes to other even $n$'s.

Comment: Nice observation!